# VLAN Tagging HP Switch

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan

Is there a way to "TagAll" VLANs on a HP Switch Port as it would be in a Cisco environment (by default on a cisco trunk port all VLANs are allowed, or one can explicilty define "allowed vlans tagall -> which then again is default config and won't show up in the running conf)
So far on HP Switches I am only aware of the ability to "vlan x tagged port y". Everytime I created a new vlan on the HP switch I would have to add it tagged to the port if.

Any one know of any options?

thanks

Comment: I think there's no other way than `vlan x [un]tagged port y`

Comment: What model switch are you using?

Comment: I thought there was nothing else.

Comment: Using 29xx and some zl5xxx

Comment: "tagall" is NOT the default on any Cisco switch. The native vlan (aka PVID) is not tagged.

Comment: sure, of course, I wasn't referring to everything on the "trunk" being tagged, just all other vlans but the native are tagged. It would have been better, had I said the default was "allow all" as the dot1q tags are by default all allowed over the trunk link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what version of ProCurve you are running, you should be able to do `tagged all` and `no tagged all` to tag every port on the switch to that VLAN, but you will need to do this for each VLAN unfortunately.

Comment: Do you mean you can add a tagged vlan to all ports? Or all tagged vlans to one port?

Comment: @Max Unfortunately, you can't tag an interface to every VLAN at once, you must do each VLAN individually, but you can tag every interface to a VLAN by running `tagged all`.

Comment: tagged ALL, where ALL refers to all interfaces, not all vlans?

Comment: @Max Correct, you can use `vlan x tag all` to tag all interfaces to your vlan, but you can't specify multiple VLANs at once.  For instance `vlan 1,2,3 tag all` is an invalid command.  You would have to do `vlan 1 tag all`, `vlan 2 tag all`, etc.